# Django Encrypt FileField with Fernet object has no attribute '_committed' occurred

Tags: python, django, fernet

I am passing multiple pdf uploads into the view from a form. (using Uppy.XHRUpload)

I want to encrypt them before saving them in the model.

When i test the files they can be encrypted and saved to a file and then read and decrptyped just fine.

But when I try to add to the model I get:

```
 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed' occurred.
```

I can download enctryped file, re-read and then save but that would be a waste.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:

    files = request.FILES.getlist('files[]')

    for index, file in enumerate(files):

        f = Fernet(settings.F_KEY)

        pdf = file.read()
        encrypted = f.encrypt(pdf)

        PDF_File.objects.create(
            acct = a,
            pdf = encrypted
        )
```

The Model.

```
class PDF_File(models.Model):

     acct = models.ForeignKey(Acct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='_temp/pdf/')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's cause you cannot save encrypted(bytes) to model

try this

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    f = Fernet(settings.F_KEY)
    pdf = file.read()
    encrypted = f.encrypt(pdf)
    content_file = ContentFile(encrypted, name=your_filename)
    PDF_File.objects.create(
        acct = a,
        pdf = content_file
    )
```

ref from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Amazing.  And it even allows me to solve a name change issue.  Thank you, thank you, thank you...